# How to add different images in three divs using the same class

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
        <div class="main_flex">
            <div class="flex_items">

            </div>
            <div class="flex_items">

            </div>
            <div class="flex_items">

            </div>
        </div>

javascript:
     function shoe_images () {
           for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){
           var getFlexItems = document.querySelector('.flex_items');
           var createImgTag = document.createElement('img');
           createImgTag.src = shoes[i].imageUrl;
          getFlexItems.appendChild(createImgTag);
       }
    };
```

And i have an array of object with different images. I want to add different images to the 
class="flex_items"

How do i do that? I used a for loop, but all the images shows in the first class="flex_items".

Comment: you should show what you did in the for loop

Comment: The objective here is for people to help you fix *your code*, not to write it all for you. Show us the script you have problems with

Comment: @charlietfl maybe he doesn't know how that

Comment: @Joseph Fine...that is why I am explaining it. It is also well outlined in the Question Wizard and in the [help]

Comment: I have updated it now....

Comment: So `querySelector()` only returns the first matching element ... not the whole collection. You need `querySelectorAll()` instead and loop over them

Comment: Also tried that but getting error: Uncaught TypeError: getFlexItems.appendChild is not a function at shoe_images

Comment: @Crazybk123 could you check my answer it may help you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the querySelector() method. This method return only the first element. It is the reason for this.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

You need to use **querySelectorAll()**

See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Rewrited your code:

```
function shoe_images () {
       var getFlexItems = document.querySelectorAll('.flex_items');

       for (var i = 0; i < shoes.length; i++){
           var createImgTag = document.createElement('img');
           createImgTag.src = shoes[i].imageUrl;
           getFlexItems[i].appendChild(createImgTag);
       }
```

Comment: Ahh that worked :) So i tried the querySelectorAll(), but didnt work. I did notice however the last line in the code you wrote....getFlexItems[i].appendChild(createImgTag). I forgot to add [i] in getFlexItems. Thank you it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by css or by js
this for CSS

```
.flex_items:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
.flex_items:nth-of-type(1) {
    background: #324445;
}
```

to used js

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('flex_items');
it will return arry contain  3 elment [0,1,2]
elements[0].innerHTML ='<img src="path">';
elements[1].innerHTML ='<img src="path">';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `flex_items` then append the element image like this:

```js
const images = [{
  src: "https://picsum.photos/id/284/200/300"
}, {
  src: "https://picsum.photos/id/284/200/300"
}, {
  src: "https://picsum.photos/id/284/200/300"
}]

document.querySelectorAll(".flex_items").forEach((el, index) => {
  const image = document.createElement("img");
  image.setAttribute("src", images[index].src);
  el.appendChild(image);
})
```

```html
<div class="main_flex">
  <div class="flex_items">

  </div>
  <div class="flex_items">

  </div>
  <div class="flex_items">

  </div>
</div>
```